# How to use python2.7 to remove first five words from a line?

Tags: python-2.7

For example, if I have the following line:

"I want to remove first five words and I do not know how to do that."

And I want to change the line to :

"five words and I do not know how to do that."

I am wondering if there is some built-in function to help me to do that and thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = "I want to remove first five words and I do not know how to do that."
print ' '.join(a.split()[5:])
```

Comment: Haha love the how you made it a two liner!